# Probability axioms does not make sense?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, axioms

Assume a unit square to be sample space (infinite points inside it being its elements). Let the points are $\{p_1, p_2, ...\}$
then, by probability axioms,
$$1 = Pr(p_1 \cup p_2 \cup  \cdots ) = Pr(\{p_1\}) + Pr(\{p_2\}) + \cdots  + Pr(\{p_n\}) = \\
     = Pr(p_1) +  Pr(p_2) + \cdots  + Pr(p_n)
     = 0 + 0 + \cdots   $$                  (as Pr of individual point in space is zero)
$= 0$

Where do I lack in understanding the logic of axioms?

Comment: There are *continuum* many points in the square, much more than countably infinite. Their set is **not enumerable**.

Comment: The unit square is not a countable set. You cannot list its elements in a sequence $\{p_1,p_2,..\}$.

Comment: @Nitesh Tripathi. I inserted mathjax in what it was, but, do I correctly think, that you want to have infinite sum in second and third members of equality chain?

Comment: There is no "probability axiom" that states Pr({p})=0 for points p. Do not think that in a sample space all outcomes are necessarily equiprobable. you just proved that by continous distribution  *countable* subsets have probability 0. This does not contradict "probability axioms" either.

Comment: @zkutch Yes, you are correct. Thank you so much for adding Math symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no sequence $(p_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of points of the unit square $S$ such that $S=\{p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots\}$. In other words, $S$ is not countable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am assuming that probability of single point in square is zero (correct me if I am wrong here). Then, summation of probabilities for all the points, even if it is uncountable, should be zero. Thus the question remains same. Sorry, if I am not making sense here. Please clarify this as well.
Thanks :)

Comment: Assuming that the probability of single point in square is $0$ is a natural assumption, yes. But how do you jump from that to “summation of probabilities for all the points, even if it is uncountable, should be zero”?

Comment: Thanks. I have understood where I was failing in logic.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.